# Adding a struct int and a normal int. c++

Tags: c++, struct

I'd like to add an int from a struct with a regular int in c++. Is there an easy way to do it? Ive searched pretty much everywhere but theres nothing on adding either two struct ints while reading in data from a binary file or adding a regular int and a struct int together.

This is the simple version of what I currently have.

```
 struct Add{
    int k;
    };

    int total;

    Add a;

//read in first set of number from binary file
    total += a.k; 
//add up to total, then read in second set of number from binary file.
```

The problem is, when I output total, it only gives me the last number I tried adding int k to it and not the total.

My actual code as requested.

```
struct TaskInit{
    int weight;
};

TaskInit t;

    int totalWeight;

    for (int i = 1; i <= noOfRecords; ++i)
    {
        afile.seekg ((i - 1) * sizeof (TaskInit), ios::beg);
        afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&t), sizeof (t));

         totalWeight +=  t.weight;

    }
   cout << totalWeight;
```

Comment: Did you mean `total += a.k`? Accessing struct elements with `structVar.element` is correct. Where is the problem? And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes i meant that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Ok, then what is your error message/problem? I see nothing wrong with the above code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I output int total, it is only giving me the last number I tried adding to it.

Comment: Isn't the current way simple enough? You may consider operator overloading for the structure `Add`

Comment: "When I output int total, it is only giving me the last number I tried adding to it." That would be because your code was as you had it prior. `total =+a.k`. That code says "take a.k, apply a unary `+`, then *assign* that to `total`. Thus your last value will be the only one that counts. if you try it as-written now it should work as you expect. `+= means add-and-assign. `=+ is two different operators and mean something entirely different.

Comment: Show a complete example.  The code shown here has nothing to do with the problem you describe.

Comment: Alright here it is. Check edits.

Comment: What is t? How is it defined?

Comment: 90% of this code is irrelevant for the actual problem. Try to narrow it down and don't include any `cout` lines, they're just noise.

Comment: t is the struct instance I initialized for the structure. My code is over 2000 lines in total so sorry if I left some crucial stuff out here.

Comment: Reproduce your problem separately from your project, and show us that code. Make it small and complete. Maybe 15 lines.

Comment: This is more readable I hope.

Comment: Does your real code also start with an indeterminate value for `totalWeight`? because as-written, the results are going to be undefined. You don't initialize the variable to `0` at the outset prior to your loop.

Comment: totalWeight was not initialized to zero. It fixed the issue! List it as the answer Ill mark it as the right one @WhozCraig.

Comment: @AceHahn Tag Hassan's answer below. It *does* initialize to zero. And after all the work he and others put into it, he deserves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Add{
    int k;
    };

    int total = 0; // no indeterminate values. always init locals!

    Add a;
   // open your file here. 
  while (inFile >> a.k) {

//read in first set of number from binary file
//add up to total, then read in second set of number from binary file.
      total += a.k;
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you initialize `total` to zero.

Comment: This is not the correct way to check for eof. Should be `while (inFile >> a.k)`.

Comment: `// some compiler set to 0 by default, though` No it really doesn't

Comment: total just needed to be initialized to zero. Now it works. Thanks!